# sending different email notification while registration based on user role

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, email

I have a website with two user role named “A” and “B” when anyone doing registration with "A" then i want to send a welcome email and when with “B” wanna send different welcome email, is it possible?
Thanks in advance

Comment: We love to help you but without knowing what you've already tried yourself so far and where exactly you are stuck the only valid answer to this question would be: Yes, sure it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. WordPress defines a function named [`wp_new_user_notification`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_new_user_notification/). You can override this function by creating your own version (also named `wp_new_user_notification`) in your own theme or plugin.

You may wish to start by copying the [contents of the existing core version](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/2e6e53d26f69c1c486bd021710c61d02dd9e144e/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1770) into your own copy. You can now customize the logic for your own needs.

Since this function passes the `$user_id` as the first argument, you can use [`get_userdata`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata) to obtain more information about the user (for example that user's roles) and then send different content depending on their role.

```
$user_data = get_userdata( $user_id );
if ( ! empty( $user_data->roles ) ) {
    if ( in_array( 'role_a', $user_data->roles, true ) {
        // custom content for role a
    } elseif ( in_array( 'role_b', $user_data->roles, true ) {
        // custom content for role b
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Jared Cobb,
Thanks for your reply, i wrapped your code like this way but I am getting syntax error. 
would you mind to review the code please?
https://codeshare.io/5NKnlm

Note that: i added these two user roles on my website

Comment: @raselmahmud lines 2 & 3 needed to be:
`$user_data = get_userdata($user_id);`
`$user_email = $user_data->user_email;`

The variable `$user` needs to be `$user_data`

Comment: i have changed `$user_data = get_userdata($user_id);` to `$user = get_userdata($user_id);` on line number 2 but still not working and getting a  syntax error on line number 7

Comment: i have updated code here https://pastebin.com/EBricGkC

Comment: i have solved the issue. there was an issue ")" bracket on line 3. that line will be  `if ( in_array( 'role_a', $user_data->roles, true ))`
Thanks for your great help, i am so kind of you

Answer (score 0):

i have solved the issue. Thanks for your great help @jared-cobb

```
            function send_welcome_email_to_new_user($user_id) {
            $user = get_userdata($user_id);
            $user_email = $user->user_email;

            // email will send only for "A" registers
            if ( in_array( 'A', $user->roles )) {
              $to = $user_email;
              $subject = "Hi A, welcome to our site!";
              $body = '
                        <h1>Dear A,</h1></br>
                        <p>Thank you for joining our site. Your account is now active.</p>
              ';
              $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
              if (wp_mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
                error_log("email has been successfully sent to user whose email is " . $user_email);
              }
            }

            // email will send only for "B" registers
            if ( in_array( 'B', $user->roles )) {
              $to = $user_email;
              $subject = "Hi B, welcome to our site!";
              $body = '
                        <h1>Dear B,</h1></br>
                        <p>Thank you for joining our site. Your account is now active.</p>
              ';
              $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
              if (wp_mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
                error_log("email has been successfully sent to user whose email is " . $user_email);
              }
            }

            }
            add_action('user_register', 'send_welcome_email_to_new_user');
```